# Material UI: How to make a horizontal Radiogroup / Formcontrol only as wide as its contents

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, layout, material-ui

I want to make a horizontal Radiogroup with a border around it in Material UI (in a React App).

I am trying to code this is such a way that the border fits snugly around the contents. However, after I've done everything I know how to do, the border still goes the full width of the parent div. To my knowledge, `display: 'inline-block'`  should get me what I want, but somehow it does not.

How can I get what I want?

Edit: It seems the problem was in the parent `<Grid container>`, which by default has `alignItems="stretch"`. Setting this to `flex-start` instead solved the issue.

Here is a [demo codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-nightingale-cku7e?file=/src/demo.js).

Below is the code I am using, and below that a picture of what the result is:

```
const styles = theme => ({
    
  ...
  
  small: {
    padding: 0,
    margin: 0,
  },
  bullet: {
    padding: 0,
    margin: 0,
    marginLeft: "0.5em",
    marginRight: "0.25em",
  },

  bulletBox: {
    borderStyle:"solid",
    marginTop:"0.5em", 
    borderWidth:"1px", 
    padding:"0.2em", 
    borderRadius: "0.3em", 
    borderColor: theme.palette.info.main,
    display: "inline-block",
  },
})


...

class ModUser extends React.Component {
    ...
    render(){
        return(
        ...
        
        <Grid className={classes.main} container direction="column" >
            ...
            
            <FormControl className={classes.bulletBox} hidden={this.state.mode === "empty"}>
              <RadioGroup direction="row" style={{display:"inline-block"}} aria-label="doc_status" name="doc_status" value={this.state.current.doc_status_sid} 
                onChange={e => {this.setState({current: {...this.state.current, doc_status_sid: parseInt(e.target.value)}})}}>          
                <FormControlLabel className={classes.small} value={1} control={<Radio className={classes.bullet} />} label="ACTIVE" hidden={this.state.mode === "empty"}/>
                <FormControlLabel className={classes.small} value={2} control={<Radio className={classes.bullet}/>} label="CLOSED" hidden={this.state.mode === "empty"}/>
              </RadioGroup>   
            </FormControl>
)}}
```

Why is the border at the blue place and not at the red one?
[image: Why is the border at the blue place and not at the red one?]

Comment: Please create a demo out of it: https://codesandbox.io/dashboard

Comment: @m4n0: ok I did that, and in so doing found the issue :)